# Removing quotes that appear in a string

Tags: string-manipulation

I'm trying to remove "" from the pattern "true" in the string

```
str1 = "{\"query\":{\"departmentnumber\":\"353B\",\"isactive\":\"true\"},\"\
fields\":{\"sn\":\"true\",\"givenname\":\"true\",\"uid\":\"true\",\"\
departmentnumber\":\"true\",\"_id\":\"false\"},\"limit\":200,\"sort\":\
[{\"departmentnumber\":\"asc\"},{\"sn\":\"asc\"},{\"givenname\":\"asc\
\"}]}"
```

I tried using

```
StringReplace[str1, "true" -> true]
```

But got this instead

```
"{\"query\":{\"departmentnumber\":\"353B\",\"isactive\":\"" ~~ true \
~~ "\"},\"fields\":{\"sn\":\"" ~~ true ~~ "\",\"givenname\":\"" ~~ \
true ~~ "\",\"uid\":\"" ~~ true ~~ "\",\"departmentnumber\":\"" ~~ \
true ~~ "\",\"_id\":\"false\"},\"limit\":200,\"sort\":[{\"\
departmentnumber\":\"asc\"},{\"sn\":\"asc\"},{\"givenname\":\"asc\"}]}\
"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand. Your output seems to indicate that it worked: what did you want instead?

Comment: I just want true without any of the ~~ or "" surrounding it.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `"true"` represents the string with content `true`, not `"true"`. To get the string including the quotes, you need to add them to the string, which means it should be `"\"true\""` (the `\` is to escape the `"`, so that it is not confused with the end of the string). And you want to replace it with the string containing `true`, that is `"true"`. Put together, this gives:

```
str1 = "{\"query\":{\"departmentnumber\":\"353B\",\"isactive\":\"true\"},\"\
fields\":{\"sn\":\"true\",\"givenname\":\"true\",\"uid\":\"true\",\"\
departmentnumber\":\"true\",\"_id\":\"false\"},\"limit\":200,\"sort\":\
[{\"departmentnumber\":\"asc\"},{\"sn\":\"asc\"},{\"givenname\":\"asc\
\"}]}"

StringReplace[str1, "\"true\"" -> "true"]
(* "{\"query\":{\"departmentnumber\":\"353B\",\"isactive\":true},
  \"fields\":{\"sn\":true,\"givenname\":true,\"uid\":true,\"departmentnumber\":true,
     \"_id\":\"false\"},
  \"limit\":200,
  \"sort\":[{\"departmentnumber\":\"asc\"},{\"sn\":\"asc\"},{\"givenname\":\"asc\"}]}" *)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Lukas! That works - gani.